# SQL Distinct count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables.

```
Table1
id   dept
100  A

Table2
id   dept
100  B

Table3
id   dept
100  C
100  D
```

My query and the outcome count 2
I need outcome count 1 for ID 100 regardless dept field. Mean not count duplicate ID on table3.
Not sure why distinct not working. Thank you.

```
select distinct count(t3.id) countid
from table3 t3
join table2 t2 on t3.id = t2.id
join table1 t1 on t3.id = t1.id
group by t3.id
```

Comment: It's `COUNT(DISTINCT())` not `DISTINCT COUNT()`. With `DISTINCT COUNT(*)` DISTINCT applies to the results of count, returning each value just once

Comment: How about using `select 1` if you always want `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
select count(distinct (t3.id)) countid
from table3 t3
join table2 t2 on t3.id = t2.id
join table1 t1 on t3.id = t1.id
group by t3.id
```

Comment: I see need the distinct inside the quote. Exceeeeelent.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try with below query:

```
select t1.id, (case when count(t3.id)>0 then 1 else 0 end) as countid
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
join table3 t1 on t1.id = t3.id
group by t1.id
```